# XML embedding base64 encoded images in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml, base64

I'm trying with no success to embed BASE64 encoded images in an XML file with php and mySQL.
The images are stored as BLOB fields in mySQL.
The following is a part of the php script I'm developing.
The image blob field is named "filebin".
I keep on getting encoding errors (even if I set the field as CDATA)!

Please help!

```
$xml_output = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\n"; 
$xml_output .= "<products>\n"; 

foreach($result as $row){ 
    $xml_output .= "\t<item>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<id>". $row['id'] . "</id>\n";
    $xml_output .= "\t\t<filebin>".$row['filebin']."</filebin>\n";
}
```

Comment: Please don't build XML documents via string concatenation. PHP offers two very good and easy XML libraries; SimpleXML and DOM

Comment: Also, what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Example using DOM

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$products = $doc->createElement('products');
$doc->appendChild($products);
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $item = $doc->createElement('item');
    $product->appendChild($item);

    $id = $doc->createElement('id', $row['id']);

    // assuming the BLOB data is binary and not already base64 encoded
    $filebin = $doc->createElement('filebin', base64_encode($row['filebin']));

    $item->appendChild($id);
    $item->appendChild($filebin);
}

$xml_output = $doc->saveXML();
```

Comment: This page contains the following errors:

error on line 14 at column 12: Encoding error.